# @CrossOrigin annotation doesn't compile

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-7

I am using spring boot 1.5.4 and @crossorigin doesn't compile with JDK 1.7
it compiles with JDK 1.8 but I need just 1.7

Error:(19, 1) java: annotation org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin is missing value for the attribute

What should I do?
I am using InteliJIdea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating your `JDK 7` to its latest version.

I found this solution in the comments section in this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

> It says that this was a known and resolved issue in `java 1.8` and has
>   been back-ported to `java 7`. So, Update to the latest `java 7 version (7u80)` or `Java 8` version.